# Up to isomorphism - number of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be a loop-free undirected graph, where $|V| = 6$ and $deg(v) = 2$ for all $v \in V$, Up to isomorphism how many such graphs $G$ are there?

I understand this question as asking how many non-isomorphic graphs there are that satisfy:

- $G$ is a loop-free undirected graph
- $|V| = 6$
- $deg(v) = 2$ for all $v \in V$

The solution given is 2: a cycle on six vertices and a disjoint union of two cycles (each on three vertices).

**How come the answer isn't 3?** The two solutions given above and also **a disjoint union of three cycles (each on two vertices)**.

So something like 3 copies of the two-vertices cycle below.

[image: Cycle on two vertices]

Comment: What would be the degree of each vertex?

Comment: a==b c==d e==f where (a,b,c,d,e,f are vertices and == are the two edges, top and bottom). So each vertex would have degree 2.

Comment: Trying drawing the graph. Each vertex has degree 1!

Comment: Assuming that == means two edges, your example does not produce a simple graph. If we allow for non-simple graphs in the problem, the graph a--b--c--d--a  e==f also works, so the answer then would be 4. The given answer makes me believe that the problem is missing an additional assumption that the graphs are simple.

Comment: @JavaMan See drawing in post

Comment: If multiple edges are allowed, then there is a fourth solution: the disjoint union of a $4$-cycle and a $2$-cycle.

Comment: It might help to know **what book you are using** because terminology varies from one book to another, especially in graph theory. Anyway, the source of a quotation must be identified, because unattributed quotation is intellectual theft.

Answer (score 3):

Unless stated otherwise, a graph has at most one edge between any pair of vertices. Put another way, an edge is completely defined by its two endpoints, and if two edges have the same endpoints then they are in fact the same edge. Your suggestion of three disjoint 2-cycles doesn't work because 2-cycles are never permitted.

(When this condition is relaxed, the resulting object is usually called a [*multigraph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph).)

If 2-cycles were allowed, you would have missed a fourth solution: the multigraph could have been the union of a 2-cycle and a 4-cycle.

Comment: Many (most?) authors use "graph" to mean "simple graph" but in that case the modifier "loop-free" would be redundant.